# SuiteCRM: recommended way to perform custom validation inside a standard module?

Tags: validation, synchronization, suitecrm

We have an instance of SuiteCRM that has been loaded with accounts coming from an internal application, via mass import.
Now we need to keep the internal application in sync with SuiteCRM, so that when someone inserts/modifies an Account from SuiteCRM, the changes should be validated by the application too.
What is the recommended way to achieve this? Should I use an after_save hook and somehow stop SuiteCRM from saving the data if the application rejects it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on mrbarletta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50958980/3497), client-side I ended up overriding the `check_form` function to perform my whole-form validation via an AJAX call to the internal application.
A bare-bones version of the function:

```
// Overriding check_form() from jssource/src_files/include/javascript/sugar_3.js

function check_form(formname) {
    if (typeof(siw) != 'undefined' && siw && typeof(siw.selectingSomething) != 'undefined' && siw.selectingSomething)
        return false;

    if (validate_form(formname, '')) {
        // SuiteCRM thinks the form is OK, let's hear my internal application
        if (my_ajax_validation_call(formname)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("The internal application couldn't accept the data");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(To include a custom script using SuiteCRM's Extension framework, I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964007/3497))

Answer (score 1):

Best scenario would be doing both validations, JS (using addToValidate) and the before_save hook (you don't want to save it if its not validated).

For the JS part you can use something like

```
addToValidateCallback("EditView", "name", "varchar", required, "invalid name", function(a,b)
{
return customValidationThatReturnsTrueFalse();
})
```

returning false will block the form.

For a more secure validation, you should do the same validation in the `before_save` hook.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken addToValidateCallback allows to validate just one specific field, what if I have to validate the form data as a whole?

Comment: That functions runs only once when the save button is clicked, not before, so you can run your entire validation in 1 single callback :)

Comment: You mean, I could register a "validate callback" on one field and perform validation on ALL the fields there?